# how to config and run objective C test cases in Xcode--XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xctest

I was reading the document of XCTest(and personally i think the documentation for this part is not that enough) and I thought I should give it a try for a new project(a MAC command-line project, not and iOS project). and then I faced complaints about linking issues--the test case building failed because the conresponsding class .o(if I am not wrong) files are not found. (the error mes here was not recorded by me, sorry)

Then I wanted to delete the test project and in the end I did not even manage to remove the test project. So seriously, how to remove an exsiting project from the solution if the notion in VS applies here?

After failing at that, I removed the auto-generated test file and created my own test case file and strangely, although Xcode detects the existence of the new test case and test method, the build failed and it failed with no issues--no linking issue, no syntax or whatever issue but it just failed. Now I do not know how to move on now as I do not even get a complaint or an error.

Comment: You may want to start over with a fresh project, to see how they're connected. When it works, the tests are linked against production code. Make sure tests go in the test target, and production code goes in the app target.

Comment: I looked at [link](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) and now the issue about linking is gone. but I got test fail even if I do "XCTAssertTrue(1==1,"")"! and I do not see any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about the state of your project to be certain what the problem is, but here is something to consider: If Xcode added a new build target for your tests, be sure that the .m files that contain the classes you are testing are included in the new build target. You can do this by clicking on the relevant .m file in the Project Navigator and looking at the "Target Membership" in the File Inspector pane. Make sure the box is checked next to the test target.

Comment: I looked at [link](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/) and now the issue about linking is gone. but I got test fail even if I do "XCTAssertTrue(1==1,"")"! and I do not see any issue

Comment: is there any tutorial that I can follow? i mean really detailed one... what do you mean in your answer? i did not really follow that